# How to know where a message is in RabbitMQ

Tags: go, rabbitmq, microservices, messaging

I am writing a service using Go and using RabbitMQ for messaging. I need to add information in the header that should contain where the message flows through, it should add the `exchange` name or the `queue` name in the message header as and when it enters one.

Can someone tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every delivered message has a set of properties. Two of these are the exchange used to route the message, and the routing key. Depending on the type of exchange you can also figure out the queue name based on this information.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html

If you need to know when a message is published you can use this plugin - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp